# confused by capital I in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I follow these step whenever I want to comment a block of code:

> ```
> 1) Enter Blockwise Visual mode by hitting CTRL-V.
> 2) Mark the block you wish to comment.
> 3) Hit I (capital I) and enter your comment string at the beginning of the line. (// for C++)
> 4) Hit ESC and all lines selected will have
> ```

However, I am not quite sure what **I** does there.  **And why ESC causes the insert on each line in the block.**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In block select mode `I` tells VIM to switch to insert mode with the cursor before the first character in the first line of the block.

All of the characters that you type **on that first line** will be inserted in front of **all of the lines** in the selection, right before the selected block.

You can do the same with `A`, except that you will add it *after* the block.

Comment: this explains it much better than my answer.

Answer (score 6):

from `:help I`

> ```
> Insert text before the first non-blank in the line
> [count] times.
> When the 'H' flag is present in 'cpoptions' and the
> line only contains blanks, insert start just before
> the last blank.
> ```

inserts before each selected line

I can only make the assumption that "ESC" is used because it's not a printable character as ENTER is.

Answer (score 3):

When using **I** , **A** or **c** in visual-mode, you are using actually the so called blockwise-operators. Yes, they behave very different in visual-mode than on insert.

For more help, `help :blockwise-operators`

Comment: instead of proving a link, provide an explanation. the link may not exist in 10 years. thx

Comment: Do you mean they behave very differently in visual mode than in normal mode? In insert mode they just type the characters haha (I realize this is an old post, but it still applies)